# reStructuredText Abstract appears in front of title, otherwise not recognized

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

## Intro

I use (Python) Sphinx to create my personal homepage. It is a collection of technical articles and lately I notices that I write articles that are more of a blog type. Still I like to have a hierarchy other than a linear timeline of posts.

I was trying to get a [RSS feed plugin](https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/sphinx-contrib/src/1621e337bb236e17d9e3fe4e98976365c06cc5fb/feed/?at=default) to work and realized that this needs proper document meta data to work properly. There are [bibliographic fields](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#bibliographic-fields) and there it says:

> When a field list is the first non-comment element in a document (after the document title, if there is one), it may have its fields transformed to document bibliographic data.

## First Try

So I assumed that I can do the following and get it right:

```
.. Copyright © 2014-2016 Martin Ueding <dev@martin-ueding.de>

###################################
The Idiosyncrasies of Bash's quotes
###################################

:Date: 2014-07-13 00:00:00
:Abstract:
    The Bash shell has many quirks and takes a lot of time to master. The Fish
    shell has a cleaner syntax but is not installed on many systems. The quote
    idiosyncrasy of Bash is presented.
```

Rendering this gives the following:

> [image]

Missing is the output of the document meta data. I added some little snippet to the template:

```
{% if meta is defined %}
<p>
{% for key, val in meta.items() %}
{{ key }} → {{ val }} <br />
{% endfor %}
</p>
{% endif %}

{% block body %} {% endblock %}
```

The `Date` and `Abstract` fields just get converted to a table. This is okay-ish for humans but does not help much in feed generation as I need a hard date.

## Second Try

So perhaps my interpretation of “after the document title, if there is one” is wrong. So I now did the following:

```
.. Copyright © 2014-2016 Martin Ueding <dev@martin-ueding.de>

:Date: 2014-07-13 00:00:00
:Abstract:
    The Bash shell has many quirks and takes a lot of time to master. The Fish
    shell has a cleaner syntax but is not installed on many systems. The quote
    idiosyncrasy of Bash is presented.

###################################
The Idiosyncrasies of Bash's quotes
###################################
```

And there one sees that the meta data is picked up nicely:

> [image]

However, the abstract is in front of the title! This is a deal-breaker as this just does not look right. I like that my actual `div.abstract` CSS styling is now used.

## Tried So Far

A workaround would be to just move the `Date` field up such that the RSS feed extension can pick up the date. Then in the theme I would have to somehow put in the date on the page. Or I duplicate it such that it is in a human-readable form in the table below the title and another copy before the title. This way I could control when updates to the RSS feed happen.

Alternatively I could add the title again in the template because I have the `title` variable there even if the title comes below this meta data table. Then I would need some CSS to remove the second `<h1>` from the page such that it looks like I want it. But that seems like a kludge and will break without CSS (which I guess is not too much of a requirement, otherwise the title will be duplicated).

Removing the copyright comment does not change anything, either.

## Open Question

Is there a better way? Can I have the title first and still get Sphinx to pick up the meta data correctly?

Comment: Maybe you could have a look at [Tinkerer](http://tinkerer.me/) - Tinkerer is a Python blogging engine/static website generator powered by Sphinx.